How to play generated audio from Edge TTS directly to speaker without saving it first?
This is the code for saving the audio from edge tts
import asyncio
import edge_tts

voices = [ 'en-US-GuyNeural']
text = "Hi this is the test"
voice = voices[0]
output_file = "test_results.mp3"

async def amain():
    communicate = edge_tts.Communicate(text, voice)
    await communicate.save(output_file)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(amain())
finally:
    loop.close()

I want to play the audio directly without saving the audio file first. How to do it?

Using pyaudio, Instead of writing these bytes to a file. You can write them to a stream and stream will play these bytes accordingly.
Sample Code -
import pyaudio
import edge_tts

text = "Hi this is the test"
voice = 'en-US-GuyNeural'
text_to_tts = "Hello World"

# Configuration
AUDIO_FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 24000  # coqui (24000), azure (16000), openai (22050), system (22050), msedge (24000)

# Initialize PyAudio
pyaudio_instance = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pyaudio_instance.open(format=AUDIO_FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, output=True)

# Function to play audio stream
try:
    communicate = edge_tts.Communicate(text, voice)
    for chunk in communicate.stream_sync():
        if chunk["type"] == "audio":
            stream.write(chunk['data'])        
finally:
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    pyaudio_instance.terminate()


Though there is a problem with playing mp3 chunks from edge-tts using pydub. Look here - https://github.com/KoljaB/RealtimeTTS/pull/113
